# spring cloud quick-start demo maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-cloud

I want to learn Spring Cloud from the official demo.

https://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/#quick-start

The maven pom looks like this:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Finchley.RC2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId></groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId></groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies><repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I am confused. Where is the groupId for spring-cloud-starter-config?
When i copy it into intellij, it says xml tag has empty body. How can i run the demo?

Comment: It's missing for some reason. Should be `org.springframework.cloud`.

Comment: Good question. Spring documentation is deficient in many areas, including this inexplicably missing groupId. If you go to https://start.spring.io/ and add "Cloud Bootstrap" dependencies, then generate the project, the groupId that shows up in that spot is: org.springframework.cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You add groupId `<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>`

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```